# How to add res/ folder while creating JAR in Android Studio

Tags: android

How to create JAR file from Android Studio also referencing res/ folder? Below is my graddle. As of now it contains "include('classes.jar')" inside "task exportJar". Is it possible to also add resource folder?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

}

//task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete){
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

//task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type: Copy){
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    //Give whatever name you to give
    rename('classes.jar', 'Executable.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly include resources, manifest entries, assets, in addition to compiled code, you need to create an android library which exports an AAR file (not a JAR).

You do this with an Android Library.  You can create one using Android Studio with File -> New -> Module and select Android Library.  You'll notice that the build.gradle it creates has `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` which tells gradle that it's going to build an aar instead of an app.  Other app projects can then include this aar to merge all the library resources into its own.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. I tried that but here the problem is it will also install .aar (main app) along with my sample app (were I use .aar as library) which is not professional way. I need to create JAR :)

Comment: AAR is standard for Android and is used by lots of libraries.  It's the only way to get android-specific items merged into the app that declares the dependency.  You can't distribute a plain jar that does these things.  If you distribute a jar, you will only be able to include classes.